# Why doesnt this query work? (Custom Taxonomy)

Tags: custom-taxonomy

My Query

```
$my_query = array(
                'posts_per_page' => 10,
                'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'country',
                            'field' => 'id',                            
                            'terms' => array(4)
                        )
                ));
```

### Added Custom Taxonomy Using

```
function taxonomy_init() {
    // create a new taxonomy

    register_taxonomy(
        'country',
        'post',
            array(
                'label' => __('Countries (Labels)'),
                'sort' => true,
                'args' => array('orderby' => 'term_order'),
                'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'location')
            )
    );


}
add_action( 'init', 'taxonomy_init' );
```

Whats wrong with it? I have 2 posts using that taxonomy.

Answer (score 1):

you mixed the query with the register function, try this:

```
function taxonomy_init() {
    // create a new taxonomy
    register_taxonomy(
        'country',
        'post',
            array(
                'label' => __('Countries (Labels)'),
                'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'location')
            )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'taxonomy_init' );
```

the in your query use

```
$my_query = array(
                'posts_per_page' => 10,
                'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'country',
                            'field' => 'id',                            
                            'terms' => array(4)
                        )
                ));
```

since you are querying only one term you don't need to order by term_id.

if you are trying to achive something else the please explain a bit more.

Comment: Im using posts as products, so here I want to sort them down by country. So I just want to show a list of countries like categories, but right now it shows something like tags. I am using `$my_query...` in a different function and no inside the `register_taxonomy` function. I'll try this code and update you.

Comment: this doesn't work too

Comment: this will only get you products in country term_id 4, if you wan to sort, by country then that's a different query. let me know if that is what you want i'll post a new query

Comment: no I don't want to sort it, sorry in my earlier message i meant to filter them. I want to get items of `term_id` 4 but its not getting any.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mention the post_type argument.

```
    $my_query = array(
            'post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'country',
                        'field' => 'id',                            
                        'terms' => array(4)
                    )
            ));
```